# Sveltekit start.js is outside of Vite serving allow list

Tags: svelte, vite, sveltekit

I created a fresh project with `svelte`, using the commandline

```
npm create svelte@latest my-app
```

When running `npm run dev` it results into an error saying

> The request url "[path_to_workspace]/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/client/start.js" is outside of Vite serving allow list.

I tried solutions suggested in other answers, but nothing helps.
I tried the following:

Adding `['..']` to the `server.fs.allow` inside the *vite.config.js*

```
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

/** @type {import('vite').UserConfig} */
const config = {
    plugins: [sveltekit()],
    server: {
        fs: {
            // Allow serving files from one level up to the project root
            allow: ['..'],
        },
    },
};

export default config;
```

Doesn't help, error stays exacly as is.

Adding the *workspace* directory inside the `server.fs.allow` works, but shows a different error.

```
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

/** @type {import('vite').UserConfig} */
const config = {
    plugins: [sveltekit()],
    server: {
        fs: {
            // Allow serving files from one level up to the project root
            allow: ['C:/Users/Richa/Local Sites/pyro_db'],
        },
    },
};

export default config;
```

The error now is:

> 14:17:40 [vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "../../../../../../Local Sites/pyro_db/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/components/error.svelte" from "......\Local Sites\pyro_db.svelte-kit\generated\nodes\1.js". Does the file exist?

Anybody knows how to resolve this?

Comment: Why do you have the file in a place where it should not be in the first place?

Comment: @H.B. I didnt put that file there, it gets generated by svelte / vite

Comment: That is odd, a lot of files will be served from within `node_modules`, that should be accessible by default.

Comment: I didn't change anything in the configs or what so ever. I just do this: `npm create svelte@latest my-app` -> `cd my-app` -> `npm run install` -> `npm run dev`. If you do this? Do you get the same error? I am using windows 11 btw

Comment: I do not get this error (using the skeleton project, `no` to every other question). Win 10. (Also, you probably meant just `npm install`.)

Comment: Yeeah, sorry .. just `npm install` ;)